# Inserting multiple select statements into a table as values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to do something like this in SQL Server:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7) VALUES

SELECT Col1 FROM Func1(),

SELECT Col2 FROM Func2(),

SELECT Col3,Col4,Col5 FROM Func3(),

SELECT Col6 FROM Func4(),

SELECT Col7 FROM Func5()
```

I have a large number of functions which return one-value results and one function which returns 3 columns. I would like to insert all of this data into one row of a table?

I can see the function returning muliple columns as possibly being a problem?

Comment: Is Func3() a table-valued function returning one row?

Comment: @Nikola, if you mean does it contain "returns table as" and it returns one row, yes it is.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I meant. I blame my english-speaking skills. So, are all other functions the same, except they return one column only?

Comment: Your english was fine- that is how I would have described it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If all functions return just one row...

```
INSERT INTO
  MyTable (Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7)
SELECT
  f1.col1, f2.col2, f3.col3, f3.col4, f3.col5, f4.col6, f5.col7
FROM
  (SELECT Col1 FROM Func1())           AS f1
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT Col2 FROM Func2())           AS f2
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT Col3,Col4,Col5 FROM Func3()) AS f3
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT Col6 FROM Func4())           AS f4
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT Col7 FROM Func5())           AS f5
```

If the functions return more than one row, you need to join them in the normal way; with predicates that determine which left row gets joined to which right row.

Comment: Hi @MatBailie, can't we do that without cross join?

Comment: The only way to associate two data sets horizontally is with a JOIN.  As these sets are single rows, and have no predicate to join on, that gives a CROSS JOIN.

Comment: ya, but its giving improper result. Redundant data.

Comment: @Er.ShaileshS.Bankar Then your data-sets are not Single rows, in which case you need either an `INNER JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN` on which you are able to specify a predicate to join on.  In which case, please open a new question with example data, example query, expected results, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
 INSERT INTO MyTable (Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7) VALUES

 SELECT Col1 FROM Func1(),

 SELECT Col2 FROM Func2(),

 SELECT Col3 FROM (SELECT Col3,Col4,Col5 FROM Func3()),

 SELECT Col4 FROM (SELECT Col3,Col4,Col5 FROM Func3()),

 SELECT Col5 FROM (SELECT Col3,Col4,Col5 FROM Func3())

 SELECT Col6 FROM Func4(),

 SELECT Col7 FROM Func5()
```

Comment: You need to put `()`'s around all the sub-queries, and `()`'s around the complete set.  `VALUES ( (SELECT x FROM y), (SELECT a FROM b), etc )`

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove `Values and all ","`and brackets around each select statement.