# How to do Mysql insert query with multiple select statements

Tags: mysql

I have a temporary table in MySQL as:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE RolesAndPermissions(
ParentPermissions VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
ChildPermissions VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
OrgPermissions VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL);
```

Now i have 3 Normal tables in My Schema which are `ParentPermissions`,`ChildPermissions` and `OrgPermissions`. Each of these have some values in it which may be same in all these tables like `CanEdit`,`CanDelete`and so on. Now what i want to do is get the permissions from these tables and insert in the temp table. I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850328/inserting-multiple-select-statements-into-a-table-as-values) as an example to build an insert statement with multiple select queries but somehow i'm getting repetition. Like say my 3 select queries are:

```
SELECT Perm_Name FROM ParentPermissions -> Returns 19 rows
SELECT Perm_Name FROM ChildPermissions -> Returns 19 rows
SELECT Perm_Name FROM OrgPermissions -> Returns 57 rows
```

I want the result set to be exactly the same as above but im getting `19*19*57=20577` rows in temp table. Here is what my query looks like:

```
INSERT INTO
  RolesAndPermissions (ParentPermissions,ChildPermissions,OrgPermissions)
SELECT
  f1.Perm_Name, f2.Perm_Name, f3.Perm_Name
FROM
  (SELECT Perm_Name FROM ParentPermissions)AS f1
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT Perm_Name FROM ChildPermissions)AS f2
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT Perm_Name FROM OrgPermissions)AS f3
```

Please Advice

Comment: How do you plan to deal with the fact that the 3 result sets are of a different size?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I added the default as null so i'm expecting that it will take null if no value is found?

Comment: If the `Perm_Name` values from the three tables don't have anything in common, then you can't easily join them together because there is no relation.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: They do have some in common, not all. So the above query i mentioned will not work at all?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: The main reason is i want to compare these permissions later. I divided the task in 2 steps. First, try and fill the columns and then add more columns which shows difference between parent and child permissions, difference between parent and org permissions and so on..

Comment: Please post the table structure for your 3 existing tables

Comment: I think you're looking for UNION

Comment: @Strawberry: Can you explain a little bit with a related example?

Comment: No. I won't be doing that.

Comment: @Strawberry If you use `UNION`, then dataset would return 19+19+57 = 95 rows.

Comment: @RubahMalam which, by a curious coincidence, is exactly what the OP is after

Comment: @Strawberry I am not sure that was what OP need. I guess, the dataset should return 57 rows.

Answer (score -1):

It is because of the CROSS JOIN.

Try to use the second answer in the mentioned post.

I mean this:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Col1,Col2,Col3) VALUES
(
 SELECT Col1 FROM (SELECT Col1 FROM table1),

 SELECT Col2 FROM (SELECT Col2 FROM table2),

 SELECT Col3 FROM (SELECT Col3 FROM table3)
)
```

Comment: Well i don't think we can have both values and select keyword together. Its throwing error on first select itself

Comment: It's not accepting commas either between select queries